# I can't turn off BitLocker on Windows 10: "drive contains system boot information"

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning, encryption, bitlocker

BitLocker is suspended on my Windows 10. Therefore there is a warning sign on my c: drive. When I try to turn off BitLocker all together, I get the error bellow:

> Disable-BitLocker : The drive cannot be encrypted because it contains system boot information. Create a separate
> partition for use as the system drive that contains the boot information and a second partition for use as the
> operating system drive and then encrypt the operating system drive.

I get this when I run `Disable-BitLocker -Mountpoint "C:"` in powershell. The same error occurs when I try to turn off BitLocker in Control Panel.

I wonder why the drive has to be encrypted if I want to turn off BitLocker. And I don't know how I can create a separate partition as the error asks me to.

My laptop is dual boot with Linux. If any more information is required, please be kind to ask me in comments.

EDIT: here is a screenshot of the partitions for the system disk:

[image]

Windows is installed on partition 2 (unfortunately, I can only guess that from the size of drive c:)

If I run `manage-bde -status c:` I get this:

[image: manage-bde]

EDIT: a screenshot of `Get-BitLockerVolume`

[image: Get-BitLockerVolume]

EDIT: a screenshot of Disk Management:

[image: disk-management]

Comment: Are you logged-in as administrator? Try in a Command prompt in Administrator mode to run `manage-bde -off C:`

Comment: Is BitLocker protection disabled or suspended.  The warning message you quoted seems to suggest it's completely disabled. Can you provide a screenshot of the partitions for the system disk? "I wonder why the drive has to be encrypted if I want to turn off BitLocker." - If BitLocker protection is suspended, the drive is already encrypted,  but currently the protection is suspended which means the key is stored on the HDD. Please [edit] your question to include the information necessary to answer your question.

Comment: @harrymc yes, I am logger-in as administrator. And I ran that command and got the same error.

Comment: In a Command prompt in Administrator mode run  `manage-bde -status c:` and add the output to your post.

Comment: @Ramhound I updated the question.

Comment: @harrymc I updated the question.

Comment: I was really looking for the information about the layout that Disk Management provides. Can you also provide the output of Get-BitLockerVolume?

Comment: The underline issue is that your BCD contains an invalid entry. Microsoft uses the term "BitLocker Drive Encryption integrity-protected application", the problem can be fixed, provided all information required to generate a valid working answer is provided.

Comment: Your disk is fully encrypted but protection was suspended, probably because of Windows Update, but it seems that you haven't rebooted. Reboot will likely return it to normal.

Comment: @harrymc I have rebooted many times but the problem still remains.

Comment: @Ramhound I updated with a screenshot. And honestly I do not quite understand your last comment. If any more information is required, please kindly let me know.

Comment: @arsaKasra Before things get worse, do you have all your data backed up? At leaast twice?

Comment: After backing up your data, try [Repair-bde](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/bitlocker/bitlocker-use-bitlocker-drive-encryption-tools-to-manage-bitlocker).

Comment: @arsaKasra - This is the reason I wanted a screenshot of Disk Management.  I don't want to have explain how to provide your BCD. This error is caused by the BCD containing an entry for `Windows Boot Manager`, `Windows Memory Tester`, or `Resume from Hibernate` on the partition you are attempting to encrypt.

Comment: @Ramhound I am sorry, but it took me too long to understand what you exactly asked for. I updated with a screenshot.

Comment: @Ramhound I meant this as an edit to my last comment, but I was a little too late. Is there some way I can create a new boot partition now without having to perhaps deleting all the contents of c:?

Comment: You can fix this problem without deleting the contents of C.  You just have to fix the BCD entry.